# Renaming an image in Nodejs as soon as uploaded

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, formidable, body-parser

I want to store uploaded images in my nodejs application in a particular naming scheme in a serial fashion.

Suppose when I upload the first image it should be renamed to 1.png and stored. For the subsequent ones, they are stored as 2.png,3.png,... irrespective of whatever the name was when uploaded.

I can do this easily. However asynchronous code for renaming is executing before the image upload is complete.

Need some suggestions and help regarding this.

```
app.post('/projects/:uid/:qid', function (req, res) {
    try{

        var _uid = req.param("uid");
        var _q = req.param("qid");  
        var _path = __dirname + '/public/projects/' + _uid + '/'+_q;

        //console.log("projects/images uid - %s path - %s",_uid,_path);

        mkdirp(_path, function (err) {
            if (err){ 
                console.error(err);
                res.json({status:"NOT OK - Failed"});
            }
            else {  
                var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

                form.uploadDir = _path;
                form.keepExtensions = true;
                form.type = 'multipart';
                form.multiples = true;

                var img_number = 0;

                form.on('fileBegin', function(name, file) {
                    //console.log("file uploading begin -", name,file);
                    file.path = form.uploadDir +'/'+ file.name;
                    //console.log(file.path);
                    img_number++;
                });

                form.on('error', function(err) {
                    console.log("file Upload Error - ", err);
                    res.json({status:"ERROR"});
                });

                form.on('end', function() {
                    res.json({status:"OK" , number_of_images: img_number});
                });

                form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {

                });
            }
        });
    }
    catch(e){console.log("IMAGE UPLOAD FAILURE- ",e);}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

Renaming it on `form.parse()` doest the trick.

```
form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
                    var img_name = randomInt(0,100000).toString();
                    fs.rename(files.upload.path, _path +'/'+ img_name + '.png', function (error) {
                        if (error) {
                            fs.unlink(_path +'/'+img_name+'.png');
                            fs.rename(files.upload.path, _path +'/'+img_name+'.png');
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Comment: var img_name = md5(Date.now()) + '.' + file.name.split('.').pop();